# How to create an amount of panels equivalent to what is needed?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

REWRITTEN:

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h15rN.png), I have 2 panels corresponding to 2 rows in this
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzNnD.png)

I want the program to auto generate panels to how much rows the database have.

For example:

- 1 row : only 1 panel
- 2 row : 2 panels....
- 4 rows : 4 panel.

and so on. 
 
Also, if you know some Student Management Application or School Management Application, it would be much appreciated. Will try to improve mine by viewing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a prefab for every possible thing you want to be able to display (i.e. one of a panel that contains a table, one of a panel containing an announcement, one of a panel containing a chart, ...) and be sure to put in them the setters you need (in the panels you showed in the image you would need a `setTitle`, a `setContent` and a `setIcon`).

After this is done, simply query your database for the data you want to display, and for each result (i.e. for each row returned) build an instance of your prefab, fill it with the data you have in the result (use the setters) and add it to your scrollpane.

Comment: I am very sorry but how can one do it?

I was thinking of making a panel object, but I do not know how to.

Comment: Create a class that extends JPanel, and then customize it adding the content you want to display. If you're using netbeans as your tag suggests, you can create a panel form and fill it with a visual editor which is very easy, but I suggest to do it by coding so you get a better idea of how swing works

Comment: I have managed to create an example. Thank you very much! Will now try it to my main project.